# efficient way to store series of values in object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I would like to list out each and every request sent to the server, Now I am storing each request in a object with id.

```
//code sample that explain my context
function handleReq(){
this.list={};

}

var reqhandler = new handleReq;

//adding each request like this
reqhandler.list[req.id] = req;
```

Problem is my application issues lot of requests (i.e; over thousands). if the user uses the application more, proportionally the object size will increase.

Now I would like to know, is this best way to store the requests?

if it is not good, Please suggest some alternatives?

Comment: What do you need the logged requests _for_? Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access the requests by id why not use an array instead:

```
function handleReq(){
    this.list=[];
}

var reqhandler = new handleReq;

reqhandler.list.push(req);
```

Obviously, if you need to keep the requests beyond the lifetime of the current page you will need to persist the requests either to localstorage in the browser or to some server-side repository, but from the sound of your question I dont think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

how about doing something like that:

```
var requestLogger =  (function(){

  var logArray = [];
  var logObj = {};
  logObj.add = function(obj){
    logArray.push(obj);
  }; 

  logObj.get = function(){
    return logArray;
  };
  logObj.getById = function(id){
    //return log elemnt by id from array.
  };
  return logObj;

}());



requestLogger.add("new request id");
console.log(requestLogger.get());
```

http://jsbin.com/gucuzohu/1/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am actually asking about if it crosses millions of requests what would be happens?

Comment: every time you will use the add function on the requestLoggger the array will increase its size,
you will be able to add a clean method to clear the data from the array maybe using timeout

you need to take a look at this:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/memory-analysis-101